# Segmentation fault while running node in libpthread.so

Tags: node.js, centos, segmentation-fault

I've been writing a daemon in node (hosted by [`forever`](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever)) and notice that the worker process sometimes randomly dies. I added a [segault handler](https://www.npmjs.org/package/segfault-handler) to see what's up, but the typical stacktrace is... unhelpful?

```
PID 9949 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x0
/home/wesley/app/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node(+0xf60)[0x7f11dd3d8f60]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x354760f710]
[0x3d3c10b0d799]
```

*Once* I received this trace on failure, instead:

```
PID 5820 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x18
/home/wesley/app/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node(+0xf60)[0x7fdfab749f60]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x354760f710]
/usr/bin/node(_ZN4node6Buffer14MakeFastBufferERKN2v89ArgumentsE+0x168)[0x426778]
[0x1d06e36ccdfb]
```

Which *still* shows the top call in `libpthread.so` (Though preceded by a call in node proper.)

I find it difficult to believe that the segfault originates in `libpthread.so` (or... nowhere?), but that's what it looks like? Has anyone had any experiences like this in the past? Does anyone have any tips for further debugging?

I'm running on CentOS 6.5 with node v0.10.29 (from the epel repository), for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Both traces show a null pointer reference. Most likely a bug in Node, so move to a newer version of v0.10 if possible.

Without a proper gdb backtrace, its impossible to tell who is at fault here.